# Grammar of "How came false Aegisthus to kill so far better a man than himself?"

Tags: inversion

From [Samuel Butler's translation of *The Odyssey*](http://classics.mit.edu/Homer/odyssey.3.iii.html):

> And how came false Aegisthus to kill so far better a man than himself?

What is the structure of this sentence?

Answer (score 1):

There are two constructions here which sound strange in Present-Day English but were still acceptable in Victorian literary English.

1. The inversion of the subject with all verbs for questions acceptable and common right through Early Middle English (ca. 1660). It was only gradually superseded in Modern English by the Present-Day convention that restricts inversion to subject and *auxiliary* verbs. In fact that supersession is not yet complete: we still invert with *BE* even when *BE* is acting as a lexical verb rather than an auxiliary. In Butler's day inversion was still possible with lexical verbs such as *HAVE* and *would* which occur frequently as auxiliaries. The case of *COME to* is similar: this is an idiom in which *COME* followed by an infinitive marked with *to* acts as a sort of aspectual semi-modal meaning approximately *happened to* or *succeeded in*. Today we would say:

   > How did false Aegisthus come to kill ... ?  or
   >   How did false Aegisthus happen to kill ... ? or
   >   How did it happen that false Aegisthus killed ... ?
2. We still use *far* in the sense as a stronger alternative to *much* to modify adjectives in the comparative grade, but not so often as in the 19th century:

   > It is a far, far better thing that I do, than I have ever done; it is a far, far better rest that I go to than I have ever known. —Dickens, *A Tale of Two Cities*
   >   Better far to live and die / Under the brave black flag I fly / Than to play a sanctimonious part / With a Pirate head and a Pirate heart. —W.S. Gilbert, *The Pirates of Penzance*

   what we have lost since then is the corresponding construction with ***so*** far ADJer:

   > <sup>ok</sup>She is so much smarter than Katie that she will easily win the promotion.
   >   <sup>∗</sup> She is so far smarter than Katie that she will easily win the promotion.

   Today we restrict *so far* to modifying verbs or clauses, most often with *only*:

   > She is only so far smarter than Katie that you can count on her to catch more accounting errors; but Katie is much more aware of personnel issues.

A modern paraphrase of Butler's sentence might be

> How did false Aegisthus manage to kill a man so much better than he himself was?

Comment: Perhaps you could provide an even more modern paraphrase, like what someone might actually say to another person?

Comment: @CoolHandLouis Well, Homer's terms aren't much current any more. How'd that rat-bastard Aegistheus manage to take out a real badass like Agamemnon?

Comment: Or, "How could a poser like Aegisthus ever kill a guy so much better than he was?"